# Restrict location types available to specific contact subtype

Tags: contacts, contact-types, location-type

We have a contact subtype that needs to have location types of 'Postal' and 'Geographical'.

I can edit the location types list to create those entries, but is it possible to restrict the available location types for only that contact subtype so none of the default locations (which we still want for individual contacts) are shown to users?

It'd also be handy to restrict which location types appear in which fields as, obviously, a postal location for a phone doesn't make a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Erikh said you cannot control the location type options through CiviCRM UI but you can restrict filter them using either [buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) or [fieldOptions](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_fieldOptions/) hook.

If you are using drupal than you can use webform with conditional filtering to filter the options. 
HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 2):

You can not restrict location types to specific contact types in core CiviCRM. 
Obviously you can develop and extension that does this.